# Angular app - restrict access to only authenticated users

Tags: angular, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

I have an Angular4 application which is authentication against Azure Active Directory(AAD). I don't have any Login page as it is managed by AAD. What I need is: if any request to this site is not authenticated to redirect it to the AAD login page. I know how to protect routes, but how to protect whole Angular App?

Comment: one solution is you can save some value in Local storage say if user is login. `For Ex: Token` if `token` does not exists  redirect it to the AAD login page

Comment: Thank you, but where should I put this check? I'm actually using 'ng2-adal/core' so I can call `adalService.userInfo.isAuthenticated`. Should this go to app.module?

Comment: protecting the whole application can only be done on the server side, and this will depend on the technology used. one important thing is that router guards do not provide actual security, in the sense that they are frontend code that can be overridden.

Comment: @AngularUniversity If you host your app using `npm start` how would you configure the host to allow only authenticated users and authenticate agains AAD?

Comment: Ya you can set to local Storage the value when first time user logins successfully and there after you can check in `app.component.ts` `ngOnOnit() ` function very first which triggers where the valid user token exists and go on forward

Comment: Ok, but where is the bast point to check if the user is authenticated and if not redirect to AAD login page? I put it into AppModule constructor. But Im not sure if it is the right place.

Answer (score 0):

To restrict access to use Azure AD in the Angular 4 application, we can use the [Adal-Angular 4 library](https://github.com/benbaran/adal-angular4) which provided by benbaran.

And you can refer the code sample [adal-angular4-example](https://github.com/benbaran/adal-angular4-example) to integrate this library.

And please note, there is a small issue when you follow this code sample. In the `app.component.ts` to use the `adal.Config`, we need to add the following line to import it:

```
import { adal } from 'adal-angular';
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with checking if the user is authenticated or not in AppModule ctor:

```
export class AppModule {
    constructor(private readonly _authService: AuthService) {
        this.useAuthentication();
    }

    private useAuthentication() {
        if (!this._authService.isAuthenticated) {
            this._authService.signIn();
        }
    }
}
```